# Validate two words from cell using two other columns Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, formulas

I've got what's probably a simple question concerning Microsoft Excel 2013 that I just can't figure out the answer to.

I have cell **A1** that contains a name in the form of **two words**, such as "Jane Doe".

In two **separate columns**, I have **separate lists of first and last names**.

Here's what it looks like:

```
    A              B           C
1|  Jane Doe       Jane        Doe
2|                 John        Doe
3|                 Jane        Dooey
4|                 Doe         Dooey
5|
```

Here's what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to set up a validation rule in A1 that dissalows entering a two -word name that doesn't match a combination of columns B and C on some row.

How can I accomplish this?

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to find a VBA solution or an Excel would be enough?

Comment: I really need an excel formula for this one since I am trying to set a validation rule.

Comment: Do you want to actually stop the user from being able to enter anything else? Or do you want to maybe raise a flag in column D, that the entered name is not acceptable?

Comment: I want to stop the user...data validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

If u add this formula to column D then you or A, Depends on where you add the name. It's a bit tricky to add the name in the same cell as the formula

```
=IF(MATCH(LEFT(A2;FIND(" ";A2)-1);B:B;0)=MATCH(RIGHT(A2;FIND(" ";A2)-2);C:C;0);TRUE;FALSE)
```

Then you can add what ever you wanna in the `TRUE`and `FALSE`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, krib. This formula won't work for what I need, though. If I wanted to validate "Jane Dooey" from A1, it wouldn't work because MATCH will only find the first match.

Answer (score 0):

```
=NOT(ISERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&B1&"*"&C1&"*";A1;1;FALSE);VLOOKUP("*"&C1&"*"&B1&"*";A1;1;FALSE))))
```

You'd like - in my understanding - to allow any combination `"*"&"x"&"*"&"y"&"*"` / `"*"&"y"&"*"&"x"&"*"`to be accepted, e.g.
Martin Luther King Jr. |   Martin | King
Luther King, Martin, Jr.|   Martin |    King

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is really close to what I'm looking for. I need it to work the other way around though. I need to be able to validate that if A1 contains "Jane Dooey" there is a row in columns B and C where "Jane" and "Dooey" meet.

Comment: This does what you want if you accept `Jane Dooey, Jr.` too.